# UWP: Xamarin Forms app always fetches en-US

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Though I have changed the **Display and Input languages** to other languages for which I have RESX files, I always get the en-US for the below method:

```
 public System.Globalization.CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo()
    {
        return new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(
            Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0].ToString());
    }
```

Should I try something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set the new language as default:

[image]

Next, there is a catch - UWP apps by default use RESW files instead of RESX which is not a problem per se, because RESX is still supported, but the supported languages are analyzed based on the available RESW files included in the project.

You have two solutions:

### Add custom `resw` files

Create a folder `Strings` in the UWP project and inside create folders for the languages you want to support - for example `en-US`, `pt-BR`, etc.

Next inside each folder add a `Resources.resw` file by right-clicking the folder, choosing **Add**, **New Item...** and selecting `Resources File (.resw)` in the list.

This should be enough for UWP to pick up on the declared languages and generate language-specific resources.

### Modify the `Package.appmanifest`

This solution is a bit worse as it removes the automatic language detection and you will have to make sure to remember to modify the manifest each time a new language is supported. Right-click the `Package.appmanifest` file and find the `Resources` element:

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
</Resources>
```

You can replace it with a list of languages you support. The first should be your default language:

```
<Resources>
   <Resource Language="EN-US" />
   <Resource Language="JA-JP" />
   <Resource Language="FR-FR" />
</Resources>
```